# Vue.js method calls on string in tabledata

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, lifecycle

Have been task to have a look at a Vue app (gulp....react dev here) for a colleague that left the company. However it is built with a string that renders the table data in a for loop such as this:

```js
      var table = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr>";
        table += `<td id="checkUpdateBox"><input onClick=${this.updateSomeCompanies(companies[i].id)}
         type="checkbox"/></td>`;
        table += `<td>${companies[i].id}</td>`;
        table += `<td>${companies[i].name}</td>`;
        table += `<td>${companies[i].custom_fields.seno}</td>`;
        table += `<td>${companies[i].created_at}</td>`;
        table += "</tr>";
      }
```

```js
 methods: {
    updateSomeCompanies(id) {
      console.log(id);
    },

// next method and so on
```

Am trying to do an update based on the id of the company. Right now, I am just console.logging the id on the method updateSomeCompanies.

However, when the page is loading I am getting the id of the company in the console even though the checkbox haven't been clicked, how come it works like this, is the strange string loop that build the tabledata or am something strange in the code above?

Furthermore, when clicking the checkbox nothing happens?

Have tried with the `v-on:clicked` and the `@Click` (same results as above).
Console.logs all of the id's then checkbox do not work.

Comment: Isn't `onClick` a React thing anyway? The loop looks quite funky already. Is the project Vue 2 or 3 (can't be both). You should probably refactor that loop anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Suggestions :***

- As you are using `Vue.js` then no need to use Vanilla JS to create a table. You can do it dynamically in the template itself.
- Use `@click`/`v-on:click` directive of Vue to trigger the click event instead of JS `onClick`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    companies: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Alpha',
      created_at: 'test'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Beta',
      created_at: 'test'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Gamma',
      created_at: 'test'
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    updateSomeCompanies(id) {
        console.log(id);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Created At</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="company in companies" :key="company.id">
      <td id="checkUpdateBox">
        <input v-on:click="updateSomeCompanies(company.id)" type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
      <td>{{ company.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ company.created_at }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all; Legend and thank you.                    Did, refactored the whole thing in the using the v-for loop approach instead of the strange string builder approach above :)

Comment: @Anafs I am glad that it works. Kindly do accept this answer if it helps you. So that it will be helpful for other fellow developers as well.